# How to manage decoded model number

Tags: python, pandas, excel

We are improving the convenience of work by using pandas.
It is possible to read, write, and modify basic Excel information through pandas.
I'd like to make a result in the following order, so please help me with how to do it.
I don't even know how to manage the information that contains the meaning of the model number.
This is a sample, but the number of models is quite large.

1. Read the data frame containing the model number in Excel.
2. Load data containing each meaning of the model number. (JSON or ???)
3. Decode the model number.
4. Decoded content is made into a data frame.
5. Save it in Excel.

**Model number conventions**
How should I manage this data?
I tried matching it with JSON, but I couldn't do it properly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axHOt.png)

**Read model number Dataframe**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4n0GW.png)

**Output Dataframe**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiwTG.png)

Comment: You've outlined the basic steps. What's stopping you implementing it?

Comment: SO is not a Programming/Homework service, can't ChatGPT do this for you

Comment: I did a lot of research and wrote it down before I asked the SO. There are language problems and I'm definitely not good enough, but is this question to the point where I get this criticism?
Please let me know if there is a case of SO similar to this.  I've already looked it up.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your goal correctly, you can use functions to parse the model number into useful data. Then you can use pandas ['apply'](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to add each column.

Here's a sample of what these functions could look like

```
def parse_product_id(model_number):
    # Can use a match statement instead of dict in python 3.10+
    p_id_dict = {'Q': 'QLED TV', 'N': 'NEO QLED TV'}
    if model_number[0] in p_id_dict:  
        return p_id_dict[model_number[0]]
    else:
        return 'Unknown'

def parse_tv_region(model_number):
    region_dict = {'A': 'ASIA', 'E': 'EUROPE', 'N': 'AMERICA'}
    if model_number[1] in region_dict:
        return region_dict[model_number[1]]
    else:
        return 'Unknown'

def parse_screen_size(model_number):
    return int(model_number[2:4])  # Conversion to integer is optional, and depends on your use case

# Continue to write more functions to parse other parts of the model number
```

Then, we use the 'apply' method on the model number for each function, and set it to a column in our dataframe

```
# This is a pairing between the column names in our outcome, to the parsing function that generates them
column_functions = {'PRODUCT ID': parse_product_id, 'REGION': parse_tv_region, 'SIZE': parse_screen_size}

# You could of course apply each function individually, but this uses less code
for col, func in column_functions.items():
    df[col] = df['ModelNumber'].apply(func)
```

I generated a dataframe that looks like this

[image: original df]

And after running the above code, it looks like this

[image: transformed df]

Comment: The 4th segment "Q60" could be either 2, 3, or 4 characters. That also means the rest of the segments might start at different positions.

Comment: Yes, OP will need to consider that. Either by slicing from the back end of the string. Or by creating helper functions for the 4th segment parsing function that gets the length of the segment, and then using that helper function in later segments to get a starting index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I think the example definitely works the way you explained it.
There was a lack of explanation.
In fact, there are quite a few other models that are not covered by the above parse rules, such as refrigerators, air conditioners, washing machines, and audio.
I thought it was also an inconvenience of management to add such codes every time I made a new model.